# Specifying the port in a pysftp connection string is not straight forward

Tags: python, pysftp

This works:

```
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

with pysftp.Connection('ftpsite.com', username='xxx', password='xxx', cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    with sftp.cd('inbox'):             
    sftp.get('WinSCP.ini')
```

But now i want to test straight ftp (port 21), so i add the port attribute:

```
with pysftp.Connection('ftpsite.com', port=21 , username='xxx', password='xxx', cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
```

and now i get this:

Exception: paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException
Message: Error reading SSH protocol banner

I am confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pysftp library only talks using the SFTP protocol, which is different from the 'normal' FTP protocol. So what you are seeing is the error when your program tries to talk in SFTP to an FTP server, and doesn't understand the response it gets back.

Answer (score 1):

SFTP use SSH so its PORT 22, not 21

FTP use port 21

Like the error said, ssh exception. Try with 'port=22'

source:

```
port 21     Yes, and SCTP   Assigned    Official    File Transfer Protocol (FTP) control (command)


port 22     Yes, and SCTP   Assigned    Official    Secure Shell (SSH), secure logins, file transfers (scp, sftp) and port forwarding
```

[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right, ftp is port 21. Pysftp defaults to 22, so if you want to test an FTP you need to explicitely state the port 21 in the string but this proves more difficult than anticipated.

Comment: So, I dont understand your trouble... explain please. Youa sked why 1/ works and not 2/. I gave you the answere. What's wrong now ?

Comment: I get this when i specify port 21: Exception: paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException
Message: Error reading SSH protocol banner and the diocumentation for pysftp does not explicitely gove the formatting example for the parameter.

Comment: ? Do the server has the port 21 open & configgured ? I dont understand your usecase, what you want, what you have and what you expect. Please, take time to explain if you want people to take time to help you